# Redirect image url that no longer exists

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

I am being asked by a client to for some 301 redirects, which I am doing via htaccess.

Most are fine, but there is one that is the url of an image that is no longer on the website. My instruction is to 'redirect these urls or get rid' (he loves to keep it short). Now the client is no longer available today and I have to finish by today, so can't go back for clarification.

SEO is not my strong suit, so what's the best thing to do with this image url? I have heard of a 410 Gone, but I don't think you do it by

```
Redirect 410 http://mydomain.com/imageurl.jpg - anyway I'm not sure its the suitable thing to do?
```

Many thanks.

Comment: What do you want to redirect the non existing image to?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a 301 redirect. Assuming you want to redirect it to the main site, you can do this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^imageURL.jpg$ http://domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So does it help you or what?

Comment: Hey, sorry. Is this the right thing to do though? Redirect it to the site? Isn't there a way of telling Google etc that this asset no longer exists? If its the right thing to do I will do it, but I was hoping for more of a consensus. I am sure you know what your talking about though so don't take it the wrong way - I just like to get a good spread of advice. Thanks for your response though.  Also the htaccess file has lots of other stuff in it, where would I place this and would it interfere with anything else? Should I put it in some kind of tag?

Comment: If you already have `RewriteEngine On` at the top of your htaccess file you don't need it again. Just place this code somewhere at the top of your htaccess without the `RewriteEngine On` part. Now as far as when site content changes a 301 is supposed to be recommended. Have a look here. http://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection

Answer (score 0):

This is corect: 
Redirect 410 http://example.com/imageurl.jpg

Redirect 410 (or "Redirect gone /myurl") tells google that imageurl.jpg is gone and you have no intention to put it back.

So, if the image is still present in search engine cache, then you should let the line in htaccess

If the imageurl.jpg is no longer in google cache, then it is safe to delete the line fro htaccess.

Hopes this help.